# Solr search within attribute having range

Tags: java, search, solr, querying

we will be having data/documents in Solr search like the following,

```
{
//..some data
age:"10 TO 29"
//some other data
}
```

i need to search based on single value like **age=15** as a search parameter. What is the best approach to search for this requirement?

Comment: You cannot use that string "10 TO 29" to search the age=15. you need preprocess you data before indexing. like upperlimit 29 and lowerlimit = 10. query can be like 15>=lowerlimit AND 15<= upperLimit.

Comment: @vinod Thank you. I can try this. i think it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to make it work like you want: if you use the [DateRangeField](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/field-types-included-with-solr.html#field-types-included-with-solr), you can index a range directly (without decompsoing into lower/upper bounds) and run a query that will hit that range.

The only thing is that DateRangeField is for Dates, if you intend to index an Age, then
you somehow need to encode the age into a date. This is easy, one simple way is to:

1. select a given date as 'Start'
2. age in years is X --> add X number of seconds to the above
3. you now have a date

The obvious downside is that the data is harder to read to he human eye. Consider if it is worth.

Comment: It might be clearer to use the spatial functionality directly to handle it instead - index a line as start, end, then use intersects to find overlapping intervals.

Comment: yes, would work too, but spatial stuff is a bit more complex to use than other types, and adding jars is a PITA